# Pulling NHL Standings from XML Table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, parsing

I'm working on a project in which I pull various statistics about the NHL and inserting them into an SQL table. Presently, I'm working on the scraping phase, and have found an XML parser that I've implemented, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pull information from it. The table can be found here -> http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/XML/NHL/standings.xml.
The parser supposedly generates a multi-dimmensional array, and I'm simply trying to pull all the stats from the "info-teams" section, but I have no idea how to pull that information from the array. How would I go about pulling the number of wins Montreal has? (Solely as an example for the rest of the stats)
This is what the page currently looks like -> http://mattegener.me/school/standings.php
here's the code:

```
<?php
$strYourXML = "http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/XML/NHL/standings.xml";
$fh = fopen($strYourXML, 'r');
$dummy = fgets($fh);
$contents = '';
while ($line = fgets($fh)) $contents.=$line;
 fclose($fh);
$objXML = new xml2Array();
$arrOutput = $objXML->parse($contents);
print_r($arrOutput[0]); //This print outs the array.

class xml2Array {

var $arrOutput = array();
var $resParser;
var $strXmlData;

function parse($strInputXML) {

        $this->resParser = xml_parser_create ();
        xml_set_object($this->resParser,$this);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->resParser, "tagOpen", "tagClosed");

        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->resParser, "tagData");

        $this->strXmlData = xml_parse($this->resParser,$strInputXML );
        if(!$this->strXmlData) {
           die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",
        xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($this->resParser)),
        xml_get_current_line_number($this->resParser)));
        }

        xml_parser_free($this->resParser);

        return $this->arrOutput;
}
function tagOpen($parser, $name, $attrs) {
   $tag=array("name"=>$name,"attrs"=>$attrs); 
   array_push($this->arrOutput,$tag);
}

function tagData($parser, $tagData) {
   if(trim($tagData)) {
        if(isset($this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1]['tagData'])) {
            $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1]['tagData'] .= $tagData;
        } 
        else {
            $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1]['tagData'] = $tagData;
        }
   }
}

function tagClosed($parser, $name) {
   $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-2]['children'][] = $this->arrOutput[count($this-      >arrOutput)-1];
   array_pop($this->arrOutput);
}
}


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this search function to your class and play with this code

```
$objXML = new xml2Array();
$arrOutput = $objXML->parse($contents);
//  first param is always 0
//  second is 'children' unless you need info like last updated date
//  third is which statistics category you want for example
// 6 => the array you want that has wins and losses
print_r($arrOutput[0]['children'][6]);
//using the search function if key NAME is Montreal in the whole array 
//result will be montreals array
$search_result = $objXML->search($arrOutput, 'NAME', 'Montreal');
//first param is always 0
//second is key name
echo $search_result[0]['WINS'];

function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array;

        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }

    return $results;
}
```

**Beware

 this search function is case sensitive it needs modifications like match to
a percentage the key or value changing capital M in montreal to lowercase will be empty**

Comment: Ok, awesome. So how exactly do I implement this? I get this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /home/matt/public_html/school/standings.php on line 10. Sorry if it's super obvious how to implement - I only started learning PHP, well, today.

Comment: I seem to getting an error with this piece of code - $search_result = $objXML->search($arrOutput, 'NAME', 'Montreal')
The error is - Fatal error: Call to undefined method xml2Array::search() in /home/matt/public_html/school/standings.php on line 17

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I sent you working in action. Pulling the data from the same link you are using also

http://sjsharktank.com/standings.php

I have actually used the same exact **XML** file for my own school project. I used **DOM** Document. The `foreach` loop would get the value of each attribute of **team-standing** and store the values. The code will clear the contents of the table **standings** and then re-insert the data. I guess you could do an update statement, but this assumes you never did any data entry into the table.

```
 try {   
      $db = new PDO('sqlite:../../SharksDB/SharksDB');  
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    } catch (Exception $e) {  
       echo "Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
       exit;
    }   
            $query = "DELETE FROM standings";
            $result = $db->query($query);

            $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
            $xmlDoc->load('http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/XML/NHL/standings.xml');
            $searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "team-standing" ); 
            foreach ($searchNode as $searchNode) {
                $teamID = $searchNode->getAttribute('id');
                $name = $searchNode->getAttribute('name');
                $wins = $searchNode->getAttribute('wins');
                $losses = $searchNode->getAttribute('losses');
                $ot = $searchNode->getAttribute('overtime');
                $points = $searchNode->getAttribute('points');
                $goalsFor = $searchNode->getAttribute('goalsFor');
                $goalsAgainst = $searchNode->getAttribute('goalsAgainst');
                $confID = $searchNode->getAttribute('conf-id');
                $divID = $searchNode->getAttribute('division-id');

                $query = "INSERT INTO standings ('teamid','confid','divid','name','wins','losses','otl','pts','gf','ga')
                          VALUES ('$teamID','$confID','$divID','$name','$wins','$losses','$ot','$points','$goalsFor','$goalsAgainst')";
                $result= $db->query($query);
            }
```